# Sharepoint 2010 upgrade to SP1. Cannot create an instance of ClassName`1[T] because Type.ContainsGenericParameters is true

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, upgrade

I have a solution deployed on my farm, it installs applications services and its correspondent proxies.

When i installed SP1 and trying to run the Configuration Wizard i get the following exception:

Cannot create an instance of MyNameSpace.SPApplicationProxy`1[T] because Type.ContainsGenericParameters is true.

i have 5 application proxies from this type MyNameSpace.SPApplicationProxy`1[T] and it seems like he is trying to invoke them by reflection...

How can i solve it? How can i make my classes not up-gradable ?